# Utility types that converts each member of an object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

How can I create a type `Promises<T>` where T is an object, such that the new type has all the same members of T, and for each member of type `T[key]` we have instead the type `Promise<T[key]>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Promises<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: Promise<T[K]> }
```

Let's test it out:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

type PromisesFoo = Promises<Foo>;
/* type PromisesFoo = {
    a: Promise<string>;
    b: Promise<number>;
    c: Promise<boolean>;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLYEsDOE0B4AqUIAewEAdgCZpQIBGAVhAMbAB8UAvFAN5QDaA0lBQkoAawggEAMyg4AugC5YiVBlz9ZrAL4AobUOJxJAQwbQAYggRdtUKEcVpgcIQHMA3DajVFJAK5JqCDgPWwZFaksAGwgjEg8dbVBIJWR0TAsrDnhUjGwM5g8AegAqKCTobJV0y3ZrW1t7FKqsR2cSFwLPW28mtKw-AKDO+qgw3tUIhGjYzs0oYsKgA)